# Copy constructors and defensive copying

Tags: java, defensive-programming

What is a ***copy constructor***?

Can someone share a small example that can be helpful to understand along with ***defensive copying principle***?

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12

Comment: You can find a detailed explanation for defensive copying here:
[Defensive copying](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15).

Answer (score 25):

Here's a good example:

```
class Point {
  final int x;
  final int y;

  Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  Point(Point p) {
    this(p.x, p.y);
  }

}
```

Note how the constructor `Point(Point p)` takes a `Point` and makes a copy of it - that's a `copy constructor`.

This is a `defensive` copy because the original `Point` is protected from change by taking a copy of it.

So now:

```
// A simple point.
Point p1 = new Point(3,42);
// A new point at the same place as p1 but a completely different object.
Point p2 = new Point(p1);
```

Note that this is not necessarily the **correct** way of creating objects. It is, however, a **good** way of creating objects that ensures that *you never have two references to the same object by accident*. Clearly this is only a good thing if that is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 11):

Copy constructors one often sees in C++ where they are needed for partly hidden, automatically invoked operations.

`java java.awt.Point` and `Rectangle` come to mind; also very old, mutable objects.

By using immutable objects, like `String`, or `BigDecimal`, simply assigning the object reference will do. In fact, due to the early phase of Java after C++, there still is a
silly copy constructor in ***String***:

```
public class Recipe {
    List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    public Recipe() {
        ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
    }

    /** Copy constructor */
    public Recipe(Recipe other) {
        // Not sharing: ingredients = other.ingredients;
        ingredients = new ArrayList<>(other.ingredients);
    }

    public List<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
        // Defensive copy, so others cannot change this instance.
        return new ArrayList<Ingredient>(ingredients);
        // Often could do:
        // return Collections.immutableList(ingredients);
    }
}
```

---

***On request***

Leaking class with copy constructor:

```
public class Wrong {
    private final List<String> list;

    public Wrong(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list; // Error: now shares list object with caller.
    }

    /** Copy constructor */
    public Wrong(Wrong wrong) {
        this.list = wrong.list; // Error: now shares list object with caller.
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list; // Error: now shares list object with caller.
    }

    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
    }
}
```

Correct class with copy constructor:

```
public class Right {
    private final List<String> list;

    public Right(List<String> list) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
    }

    public Right(Right right) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(right.list);
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(list);
    }

    public List<String> getListForReading() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
    }
}
```

With testing code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list1, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
    Wrong w1 = new Wrong(list1);
    list1.remove(0);
    System.out.printf("The first element of w1 is %s.%n", w1.getList().get(0)); // "b"
    Wrong w2 = new Wrong(w1);
    w2.clear();
    System.out.printf("Size of list1 %d, w1 %d, w2 %d.%n",
        list1.size(), w1.getList().size(), w2.getList().size());

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list2, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
    Right r1 = new Right(list2);
    list2.remove(0);
    System.out.printf("The first element of r1 is %s.%n", r1.getList().get(0)); // "a"
    Right r2 = new Right(r1);
    r2.clear();
    System.out.printf("Size of list2 %d, r1 %d, r2 %d.%n",
        list2.size(), r1.getList().size(), r2.getList().size());
}
```

Which gives:

```
The first element of w1 is b.
Size of list1 0, w1 0, w2 0.
The first element of r1 is a.
Size of list2 4, r1 5, r2 0.
```

Comment: How will assigning the object reference for an immutable object produce a copy?  Won't you just end up with two references to the same object?

Comment: @darrenmc here the recipes will be copies in the following sence: the lists of ingredients are separate instances. Every Ingredient however is shared. If Ingredient is an immutable object. like cabbage, then fine. If Ingredient is Recipe specific, say with quantity, then one would need to copy every Ingredient too. In my answer I wanted to stay at the top level, the field `ingredients`.

Comment: Beware, `BigDecimal` is not actually immutable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12600683/14731

Comment: @Gili yes as BigDecimal is not final, a BigDecimal could actually be a mutable subclass. Fortunately all BigDecimal fields are private, so using a BigDecimal constructor is unproblematic. With BigInteger - that might be used for cryptography - one might imagine some exploit.

Comment: @JoopEggen The fact that all fields are private does not make the class immutable. A malicious sub-class can use reflection to read their values. Even without access to the fields, it could return incorrect results or snoop on the application's interaction with the object.

Comment: @Gili though with BigDecimal the API has an immutable behaviour of itself, so a child class has a hard time messing up the base object. Of course it could mallciously reimplement all and reflection is always a possibility. I do agree with you. But so is the final class String. And not to forget byte code manipulation, AOP and such.

Comment: @JoopEggen  Could you modify and demonstrate the above Copy Constructor scenarios  through a Java's main method for better understanding ?

Comment: @deepakl.2000 I am on my smart phone now, and defensive copying (for containers, lists) means just one object holds the list, others should not be allowed to alter it. For this at most a copy of the list is given out. And on receiving a list in the constructor: make a copy, so the original owner that passed the list may not alter it as when it would be your class member.

Comment: Fundamental is javas pass-by-value. A list object is just a value: its "address", which is passed around. So assignment causes sharing an object (address).

Comment: @JoopEggen If you can provide the workable code, it would be great

Comment: @deepakl.2000 added to answer. And corrected the code slightly. Were you too polite to indicate an error? Please, I make them all the time at fresh code.

Comment: @Joop Eggen , Could you please add the public static void main method for Recipe Class,Wrong Class,Right Class . It will be helpful a lot.

Comment: @JoopEggen , Could you please add the public static void main method for Recipe Class,Wrong Class,Right Class . It will be helpful a lot.

Comment: @deepakl.2000 sorry, forgotten to copy.

Comment: @JoopEggen Could you please add the public static void main method Java code for Recipe Class

Comment: @Joop Eggen , Could you please add the public static void main method for Recipe Class

Comment: @deepakl.2000 Sorry, a bit stressed; less time for stackoverflow. Bye

Comment: @JoopEggen , OK when you find time, do update it. It would be useful for learning purposes. 

Comment: @JoopEggen , Could you please add the public static void main method for Recipe Class

Comment: @deepakl.2000 `class Recipe { ... public static void main(String[] args) { ... } }` For sample code creating objects and copying them, try coding yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Copy constructor in java can be used when you need to clone an object

```
class Copy {
   int a;
   int b;
  public Copy(Copy c1) {
    a=c1.a;
    b=c1.b;
  }
}
```

In java when you give Copy `c2=c1`; simply creates a reference to the original object and not the copy so you need to manually copy the object values.

See this:

- [Why doesn't Java have a copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827785/why-doesnt-java-have-a-copy-constructor)
- [Copy Constructor in Java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

This is where you create a new object, by passing an old object, copying its values.

```
Color copiedColor = new Color(oldColor);
```

instead of :

```
Color copiedColor = new Color(oldColor.getRed(),
                              oldColor.getGreen(), oldColor.getBlue());
```

Comment: That's a fairly terse answer. Care to explain why this might be done?

Answer (score 1):

A copy constructor is used to create a new object using the values of an existing object. 
One possible use case is to protect original object from being modified while the copied object can be used to work upon.

```
public class Person  
{  
   private String name;  
   private int age;  
   private int height;  


/** 
 * Copy constructor which creates a Person object identical to p.  
 */  
   public person(Person p)  
   {  
      person = p.person;  
      age = p.age;  
      height = p.height;  
   }  
.
.
. 
}
```

Related to defensive copy [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15) is a good read