# Create an independent copy of the object

Tags: java, copy, clone

How to create an independent copy of the object `route`? The problem is that all the updates applied to `route_copy` are also applied to `route`. How to avoid this?

```
public class Route implements Cloneable, Comparable<Route> {
//...
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
//...
}

public void processData(Route route)
{
        route_copy = null;
        try {
            route_copy = (Route) route.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a deep copy method in your class or a copy constructor. Check this related post to understand how to do that:

[Copy constructors and defensive copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020850/copy-constructors-and-defensive-copying)