# The copy constructor creates dependent copy

Tags: java, clone, copy-constructor

I implemented the copy constructor as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020850/copy-constructors-and-defensive-copying). But still the problem is that when I update `route_copy`, then the same update is applied to `route`. So, I don't understand what is wrong in my code?

```
public class Route implements Comparable<Route> {
    private List<Site> sites;

    public Route()
    {
        sites = new ArrayList<Site>();
    }

    public Route(List<Site> sites)
    {
        this.sites = sites;
    }

    /**
     * Copy constructor
     */
    public Route(Route r) {
        this(r.sites);
    }

    public void deleteSite(Site s) {
        this.sites.remove(s);
    }
}

public processData(Route route)
{
  Route route_copy = new Route(route);
  Site s = selectSite(route_copy);
  route_copy.deleteSite(s); // !!! now 'route' does not contain an  element 's'
}
```

Comment: Your "copy constructor" is not making a copy of the input list. Try something like

Comment: Java doesn't really support copy constructors to the same degree as C++ i.e. automatic invocation. Wouldn't overriding `clone()` be more appropriate?

Comment: @DuncanACoulter: I had the same problem after overriding the clone method and implementing the class Route as Cloneable.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Just as well probably, some searching has revealed that the current consensus is to [avoid clone](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your copy constructor, you are just doing a shallow copy, while you need to do a deep copy:

```
public Route(Route r) {
    this(r.sites);
}
```

Here, you are still copying the reference of the `list`, which still points to the same `ArrayList`. You should modify it to create copy of list too. Possibly, you also need to create copy of the elements inside the arraylist like so:

```
public Route(Route r) {
    List<Site> newSites = new ArrayList<Site>();

    for (Site obj: r.sites) {
        // Add copy of obj to the newSites
        // So you need yet another copy constructor in 'Site' class.
    }

    this.sites = newSites;
}
```

Check this post - [Shallow Copy vs Deep Copy.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/1679863)

Comment: This won't compile. `this(...)` must be the first statement in a constructor.

Comment: @damo. OOPs. Fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: ITSPoI will still referencing to the same ITSPoI in the 2 list, if you mutate object in the list will be reflected, still a shallow copy

Comment: you can serialize and deserealize the list to make a deep copy too, if the list is serializable

Comment: I think it depends on the intent. If `Site` isn't _owned_ by the `Route`, you wouldn't want to create multiple instances of the same site...

Comment: @damo. Yeah that depends. I would let OP to decide onto that.

Answer (score 2):

Your "copy constructor" is not making a copy of the input list. Try something like

```
public Route(List<Site> sites)
{
    this.sites = new ArrayList<Site>(sites);
}
```

for your second constructor.

Comment: Will this create a completely independent copy?

Comment: It will create a copy of the ArrayList<Site>, but not of the elements hold by the list itself (the Site objects).

Comment: @KlausosKlausos ... which means that while `copyList.remove()` would not affect the original list; `copyList.get(i).setSomething("")` would. So, it depends on how you're going to use the copy.

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse it'll create dependent copy also called **Shallow** copy.

You need a **Deep** copy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both lists are still pointing to the same memory location, thus, any operation on one list eventually modifies the other.

You can try and use the copy constructor of the ArrayList:

> public ArrayList(Collection c)
>
> Constructs a list
>   containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they
>   are returned by the collection's iterator.

Like so:

```
     public Route(Route r) {
     this(new ArrayList<Site>(r.sites));
     }
```

Note however that doing any modifications to the `Site` objects within the list might have repurcussions on the other objects stored in the other list, depending on how complex your `Site` object is.

Answer (score 1):

what you do with the copy constructor is just make the new `Route` use the list of the old `Route` and therefor any change to one of them immediately effect the other

what you need to do is make the copy constructor make a new list:

```
sites = new ArrayList<Site>(oldList);
```