# final Object changes the value of original Object

Tags: java, android, arraylist, final

I have a POJO class of `Contact` which holds name, email and photoUri for a contact from address book. As the activity starts, I query contacts and retrieve all contacts and assign it in `ArrayList<Contact>`. And this `ArrayList` is used to show all contacts in `RecyclerView` list.

When a user clicks on it, I open a popup with showing a alert dialog and user's name and email filled in `EditText`. User can edit the details and save it. When it is saved I add that `Contact` Object in another `ArrayList` of selected contacts list.

The problem arises when user edits some contact information and save it. It also changes the original contacts details in the all contacts `ArrayList`.

**Code flow:**

ArrayLists where data is stored:

```
ArrayList<Contact> mContacts = new ArrayList<>(); // This is filled with contact data
ArrayList<Contact> mSelectedContacts = new ArrayList<>(); // Initially empty
```

When User clicks on the contact, popup shows for editing contact details:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, final int position) {

        // Get the contact details at given position
        final Contact ci = contactList.get(position);

        ...

        contactViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createNameEmailEditDialog(ci);    // Opens Popup
            }
        });

    }
```

Method that creates the popup:

```
private void createNameEmailEditDialog(final Contact contact) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        ...

        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                    contact.setName(String.valueOf(nameEditText.getText()));
                    contact.setEmail(String.valueOf(emailEditText.getText()));
                    mSelectedContacts.add(contact);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    addViewToSeletedBar(contact);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now after the dialog dismiss, in the RecyclerView List. I can see that, edited name is also reflected in the all contacts list (`mContacts` ArrayList).

I know there is something Hard reference is going on, but where? Is it `final` that provides hard reference? Or calling `createNameEmailEditDialog()` with a `final Contact ci` is causing the damage? Or anything else?

How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference `contact` is `final` which means the reference cannot point to anything else. But the `contact` instance itself is not *immutable*. For reference types `final` is NOT `immutable`. Try creating a defensive copy of `contact` and passing it to your method (if you don't want the original instance to be changed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What do you mean by the term defensive copy?

Comment: @kirtan403 Create a constructor `Contact(Contact c)` and pass the `Contact` you got from the `List` there. In this constructor just get and set the values from the other `Contact`.

Comment: @kirtan403 - Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020850/copy-constructors-and-defensive-copying

Comment: Copy constructor is the way to go.. Thanks @KevinEsche and TheLostMind