# Creating different POJO child objects depending on criteria but share common fields

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism

I am implementing a log management system and want the types of logs to be extendible. We get a base object parsed from JSON (from Filebeat) such as:

```
class LogLine {
   String message
   Date timestamp
   String type
   String source
}
```

Given this LogLine object, I want to be able to create different objects, which will also extend this LogLine.

```
class SomeLog extends LogLine {
    int myfield
    String username
}

class SomeOtherLog extends LogLine {
   Date startTime
   Date endTime
   String username
   String transactionID
}
```

So, in my current non-ideal implementation:

```
void parse(String s){
   LogLine logLine = .....parseFromString(s)
   if ( logline.type.equals('def') ){
      SomeLog someLog = new SomeLog.Builder.build(logLine)
   } else if ( logline.message.containts('abc') ){
      SomeOtherLog someotherLog = new SomeOtherLog.Builder.build(logline)
   }
}
```

However, as you can imagine the builders in subclasses copies the superclass LogLine object, is there anyway I can do that without copying the values as they are already subclasses? Is there a design pattern to achieve this? I would not like to rely on reflection like `BeanUtils.copyProperperties`

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new object based on another it's a good idea to make a copy of all field. It's a best practice called [defensive copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020850/copy-constructors-and-defensive-copying).

Since you parse a string, a defensive copy doesn't needed. Also I suppose you'll want to parse some specific fields from input string like `myfield` for `SomeLog` and `startDate` for `SomeOtherLog`. You could re-factor object creation like

```
LogLine result = null;
if (s.contains('type=def') { 
  result = SomeLog.parse(s);
} else if (trickyRegexp.mathces(s)) {
   result = SomeOtherLog.parse(s);
} else {
   result = LogLine.parse(s);
}
```

If you have many subclasses of LogLine then probably you'll want to move creation logic to a `LogFactory` which manages all the stuff regarding parsing string to specific object.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a factory interface for creating `LogLine` objects.

```
public interface LogLineFactory {
    public LogLine createLog(LogLine logLine);
}
```

and use a `Map` for the lookup.

```
private Map<String, LogLineFactory > logLineFactories = new HashMap<>();

{
    logLineFactories .put("def", new SomeLogFactory());
    logLineFactories .put("abc", new SomeOtherLogFactory());
}
```

You can then ommit the if else branches using the map looup.

```
LogLine logLine = parseFromString(s);
LogFactory logFactory = logLineFactories.get(logLine.type);

if(logFactory != null) {
    LogLine wrappedLogLine = logFactory.createLog(logLine);
}
```

Maybe you will need more information to create the `LogLine`s and you have to change the interface.

```
public interface LogLineFactory {
    public LogLine createLog(LogLine logLine, String s);
}
```

PS: with Java 8 you might want to use method references.

```
logLineFactories.put("def", SomeLog::new);
logLineFactories.put("abc", SomeOtherLog::new);
```

Comment: The idea of using `Map` instead of `if-then-else if` pattern is great. But 'abc' substring is getting from a different field so you have to improve solution.