# Why are some of my threads changing the values in a seperate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing an assignment on multithreading and am running into the issue of values from my first thread being set as values in a separate thread. Basically the assignment is a genetic algorithm to optimize a factory floor layout.

`this.floor` is a `Floor_layout` class I have that consists of a 2d array and different stations (I call them machines in my code) are put into the array as coordinates. I initialize a floor layout in my main class and create multiple threads (only 2 right now) and send the floor layout to each of the threads. I then want to move around the stations randomly in each separate thread so they are different.

What the following code should do is print the cords of the first station then randomly change the cords of it then print the new cords and this happens for both threads. But what ends up happening is it changes the cord of my first threads machine then sets the cords of my second threads machine to the new cords of the first thread's one.

I'm sorry if this is confusing to understand and I don't know if I need to show my other classes but here's my thread class and the output from running it.

```
class Threads implements Runnable {
    boolean flag = false;
    private Floor_Layout thisFloor;
    Machine test1;

    public Threads(Floor_Layout f) {
        thisFloor = f;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            thisFloor.machineCord(thisFloor.machineArr[0]);
            thisFloor.moveMachineRand(thisFloor.machineArr[0]);
            thisFloor.machineCord(thisFloor.machineArr[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception is caught");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread 0 Machine[0] oX,oy = 4,3 aX, aY = 5,3 lX,lY = 3,3  (this line)
Thread 0 Machine[0] oX,oy = 3,1 aX, aY = 4,1 lX,lY = 2,1
Thread 1 Machine[0] oX,oy = 3,1 aX, aY = 4,1 lX,lY = 2,1  (and this line)
Thread 1 Machine[0] oX,oy = 5,3 aX, aY = 6,3 lX,lY = 4,3`
```

Both the lines indicated above should have the same cords because that's before I call the randomize cord command.

Comment: Please update the question to include the code that is setting up and executing the `Threads`.  But as a guess, in the constructor, `Floor_Layout f` is probably the same instance.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020850/copy-constructors-and-defensive-copying).

Comment: By the way, `Threads` is a poor choice of class name. The name should describe the task being performed by your `Runnable`.

Comment: Are "cords" coordinates? Does "Rand" mean "Random"? Using slang or unidentified abbreviations is not helpful, particularly on this site with its broad audience.

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your class Floor_Layout is thread safe or is not used as a singleton. You should not have any fields in the class which can be modified by any of the methods. Or if your class is intended not to be thread safe then you need to have a new instance of this class for each thread.