# I need a solution for Java's limitation in calculating and storing big numbers

Tags: java

in python with a simple loop you can calculate, let's say `600!` it's a very very big number but python can easily take care of it in a fraction of a second.even it's more than `200` digit long. 
in java in the other hand you are bound to 64bit literals (long data type). so the machine will return 0.
is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 51):

You can use the Java [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

And a simple example:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

BigInteger k = BigInteger.valueOf(10000L);
k = k.pow(10000);
//k is now 10000^10000 
System.out.println(k.toString());
```

It's important to know that the class is immutable. You can also look into the similar [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class for arbitrary precision signed decimal numbers.

Comment: you forget to mention 
import java.math.BigInteger;
Wow!thanks i love java again!

Comment: Added import statement

Comment: @Kon Nothing wrong but its better to link latest API documentation

Comment: Because the class is not final a `BigInteger` instance is only immutable if it is not a subclass of `BigInteger`.

Comment: @Joseph: Is that true; can a subclass change the internal value of the `BigInteger`?  If not, I'd say your statement is false - a subclass can add its own, mutable fields, but any method accessing an instance of that class through `BigInteger` can still treat the `BigInteger` as an immutable object.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft no it cannot, but a subclass could add some property that *was* mutable, or override the methods and return itself but with a different state -- in which case the subclass could not be said to be immutable. It is mostly a technical point -- for all intents and purposes you can probably assume anything that is an instance of BigInteger is immutable in your program. If you are designing your own library, then avoid the same mistake and make your immutable class final. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146311/immutable-class-should-be-final