# Why is Java's BigDecimal class not declared as final?

Tags: java, immutability, final

While checking the source code of Java's [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class, I was surprised that it was **not** declared as a `final class`:

> #### Class BigDecimal
>
> ```
> public class BigDecimal
> extends Number
> implements Comparable<BigDecimal>
> ```
>
> **Immutable**, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers.

(from the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html))

*Is there a specific reason for this or did the developers just forget to add that keyword? Is it a good practice to not declare immutable classes as final?*

The same goes for [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), but not for [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) which is declared as final.

Comment: I think [this specific answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12600683/1743880) answers this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quote from https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/compatibly_evolving_bigdecimal:

> However, there is a possible complication here since BigDecimal is not final and since it has public constructors, it can be subclassed. (As discussed in Effective Java, Item 13, Favor Immutability, **this was a design oversight when the class was written**.)

(emphasis mine).

Since Java has always favored backward compatibility, making it final now is out of question: it would break existing subclasses.

That said, just as when using Date, I would simply assume that no-one ever subclasses BigDecimal, and that BigDecimal should thus be used as if it were truly immutable.

Comment: Joshua mentions in the Item 15 : The Java platform libraries contain many
immutable classes, including `String`, the boxed primitive classes, and `BigInteger`
and `BigDecimal`. But as the class is not  marked as `final`, an untrusted client might provide an argument by subclassing the same. Why is he mentioning the class as immutable then?

Comment: @FarhanShirgillAnsari  You wrote: "Why is he mentioning the class as immutable then?"  I *think* he wrote this because all data members are declared as `final`: `private final BigInteger intVal;` and `private final int scale;`