# BigDecimal is extendable and has no copy-constructor. Is that a security risk?

Tags: java, security, bigdecimal, effective-java

According to Effective Java Item 24 (Make defensive copies when needed) mutable objects pose a security risk, especially when passed as constructor arguments. One is encouraged to make defensive copies as necessary.

`BigDecimal` is meant to be immutable, but it is not final. According to Effective Java Item 15 (Minimise mutability), a class cannot be immutable unless it is final or all of its constructors are non-extendable.

To make matters worse, `BigDecimal` doesn't provide a copy constructor.

So, do `BigDecimal` arguments pose a security risk? Should one go through the painful process of invoking `new BigDecimal(untrusted.toString())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33463772/14731:

> As discussed in Effective Java, Item 13, Favor Immutability, **this was a design oversight when the class was written**

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12600683/14731 BigDecimal does pose a security risk and defensive copies should be made as necessary.

Looks like the quickest way to create a defensive copy is:

```
public static BigDecimal copyOf(BigDecimal value)
{
    if (value == null || value.getClass() == BigDecimal.class)
        return value;
    return new BigDecimal(value.unscaledValue(), value.scale());
}
```

**UPDATE**: Apparently this is now explicitly discussed in Effective Java 3rd edition, Item 17 (Minimize Mutability).

Comment: Should `value.getClass() == BigDecimal.class` actually be `value.getClass() != BigDecimal.class`? I think you're meaning to defend against an class that extends BigDecimal, right?

Comment: @PatrickM No. If `value.getClass() == BigDecimal.class` then no extension took place and it is okay to return the existing instance; otherwise, we need to make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could also work:

`BigDecimal newValue = oldValue == null ? null : oldValue.add(BigDecimal.ZERO);`.

Comment: I don't think this is safe. Either you invoke `oldValue.add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` which is unsafe because `oldValue` is untrusted or you invoke `BigDecimal.ZERO.add(oldValue)` but under the hood `add()` trusts the operand when it should not so...